# C++ boost error: cannot convert const value type* (aka const wchar_t*) to const char* in initialization

Tags: c++, boost, char, constants, value-type

I'm trying to search for a word from a file using the boost module and c++ and I'm stuck on this error message:

```
error: cannot convert 'const value_type* {aka const wchar_t*}' to 'const char*' in initialization
```

The error comes from this line of code:

```
const char* file_path = itr->path ().filename ().c_str();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without looking at anything specific, `path()` is returning a `wstring`, so `c_str()` returns a `const wchar_t *`, not a `const char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is telling you you need this:

```
const wchar_t* file_path = itr->path ().filename ().c_str();
```